# Linux terminal colour highlighting?

Tags: linux, colors, terminal, highlighting

I'm wondering if it's possible to apply a customised highlighting scheme to linux terminal output, outside of the application that's generating the output. (Therefore, piping the output to some kind of colouriser would not do, because it wouldn't work for interactive output.) Ideally, you could apply some kind of regexp to each line, and a colour would be applied to each line that matches. (assuming the facility is switched on)

So, does anyone know of a terminal that offers this feature? The absolute best possibility would be something screen-like, that sits between the terminal and the shell, and processes the output without getting in anything's way.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this feature in [`zsh`](http://www.zsh.org/) using [`zsh-syntax-highlighting`](https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh-syntax-highlighting).

[image]

[FISH](http://fishshell.com/) also does this, but I have not tried it myself. (Site seems to be a little broken for now)

Comment: This seems interesting, but does this work for command line programs running within the terminal, or does it just work with the shell itself?

Comment: zsh-syntax-highlighting works for anything that you type in, not the output of applications. Take a look at 
slhck's answer here: [Where can I find bash_profile / bashrc themes?](http://superuser.com/questions/488795/where-can-i-find-bash-profile-bashrc-themes)
Edit: Don't forget that you can use aliases in your `~/.zshrc` or `~/.bashrc` such as `alias ls='ls --color=auto`.